# How to prevent multiple tree nodes creation using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jstree

I'm using the jstree plugin and when creating a tree node leaf by clicking on a the tree button, it sometimes create multiple tree nodes when I only need to create one at a time.

```
 $("#treeNodeButton").on("click", function{

       $("#treeFile").jstree("create",null,"inside",{"attr": {"rel":"SpecialFile","id":"leaf_"+fileID}});


 });
```

I tried this but it only works one time and only when I reload the page again, it works but only one time again.

```
$("#treeNodeButton").one("click", function{
     $("#treeFile").jstree("create",null,"inside",{"attr": {"rel":"SpecialFile","id":"leaf_"+fileID}});
});
```

Comment: This snippet does not seem to be complete enough to answer. Where does `fileID` come from and how is it modified? Under which conditions are multiple nodes created? It would be easier to analyze if you provided a jsFiddle or another interactive minimal example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @MasterAM This issue is not on the creation of the file. The issue is why multiple clicks are being generated but when using the one method it works, meaning it creates one node.

Comment: I got that, but have not been able to reproduce the issue, hence need a test case, preferably an interactive one.

Comment: Too many plugin required to get this working so I'm just looking for someone who may have come across this same problem using jstree plugin